# Address in shellcode changing during execution

Tags: c, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, shellcode

My goal is to create shellcode that calls `WinExec` and launches `notepad.exe`. The bare bones code is (although actually surrounded by some other `gcc` produced assembly):

```
push 0x00646170
push 0x65746F6E 

push 5

lea eax, [esp + 0x4]
push eax

call 0x76E137C0
add esp, 32
```

It pushes "notepad\0" onto the stack, then 5, then the address of the `"notepad"` string, then finally calls `0x76E137C0`. `0x76E137C0` is the address `WinExec` seems to reside at when ASLR is disabled on my machine (A 32-bit Windows 10 VM).

I'm taking this code, assembling it using `gcc` (simply `gcc shell.c -o shell.exe`), then `objdump`ing it. Once I find the instructions, I take the bytes it shows:

```
40141e:       68 70 61 64 00          push   $0x646170
401423:       68 6e 6f 74 65          push   $0x65746f6e
401428:       6a 05                   push   $0x5
40142a:       8d 44 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%eax
40142e:       50                      push   %eax
40142f:       e8 8c 23 a1 76          call   76e137c0 <.debug_str+0x76a027c0>
401434:       83 c4 20                add    $0x20,%esp
```

Then I'm turning that into a string of bytes, and attempting to execute it:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winbase.h>

int main() {

    char* shellcode =
       "\x68\x70\x61\x64\x00\x68\x6e\x6f\x74\x65\x6a\x05\x8d\x44\x24\x04\x50\xe8\xbc\x37\xe1\x76\x83\xc4\x20";

    ((void(*)())shellcode)();

    return 0;
}
```

**The problem** is, if I then compile the above simple C program and run it, nothing happens. If I open it in Immunity and step though, I can see that the instructions were preserved, *except* for the address:

[image: Immunity Debugger Screenshot]

The address is in the wrong module, and seemingly part way through a function. If I step down and into the `call`, I get an access violation. If however I restart, and in Immunity I replace the `call 77218816` with `call 0x76E137C0`, then have it continue, it works fine and notepad pops up.

I can't tell why the address is changing though while nothing else is. Does anyone see what I may be doing that's off?

---

---

The whole initial assembly is

```
    .file   "shell.c"
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .text
    .def    ___main;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section .rdata,"dr"
    .align 4
LC0:
    .ascii "notepad\0"
    .text
    .globl  _main
    .def    _main;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_main:
    lea ecx, [esp+4]

    and esp, -16
    push    DWORD PTR [ecx-4]
    push    ebp

    mov ebp, esp
    push    ecx

    push 0x00646170
    push 0x65746F6E 
    
    push 5
    
    lea eax, [esp + 0x4]
    push eax
    
    call 0x76E137C0
    add esp, 32
    
    sub esp, 8
    mov eax, 0
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR [ebp-4]

    leave

    lea esp, [ecx-4]

    ret
```

Comment: The data you have loaded into `char* shellcode` doesn't match the code in your objdump. Seems like a typo. (`\xe8\xbc\x37\xe1\x76 != e8 8c 23 a1 76`)

Comment: @th33lf Sorry, I should have mentioned, in this example posted here, the bytestring was generated via [this tool](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm) instead of `objdump`. `objdump` and it both give slightly different results for the `call` instruction, but both lead to (different) wrong addresses when run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `call` like that is EIP-relative. You're not running your shellcode at the same address you compiled it for, so it can't `call` out of itself like that. For a quick-and-dirty workaround, you can do `mov eax, 0x76E137C0` and then `call eax`, which is absolute.

Comment: Ah! That explains why I've seen that pattern elsewhere. Thanks, I'll give it a try. So, just to clarify, if I `call <address>`, it's relative to EIP, but `mov <reg> <address> call <reg>` is absolute? So it's simply a matter if the address is an immediate or not?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: x86 hasn't got an absolute direct near call instruction.  If you know the segment selector of your code segment, there is an absolute direct far call, which you can write in gas Intel syntax as `lcall 0x1234:0xdeadbeef`, but it will push 8 bytes onto the stack so it needs a far return at the other end.  Otherwise you are stuck with an absolute indirect call with the target address in a register or memory.  See https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks. I'll give that a read. And simply storing the address in a register did indeed fix it. Thank you.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Yes, storing the address in a register *is* what lets you do an absolute *indirect* call.  Using an address from a register (or data memory, rather than an immediate) is what makes it indirect.